# Keyboard will show notification called when keyboard is not present for AccessoryInputView

Tags: ios, swift, uiresponder, notificationcenter, inputaccessoryview

I have an input accessory view called chatBoxView, which contains a custom growingTextView and couple of buttons to send the message. And this inputAccessoryView is setup in my main view controller.

```
 override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
     get {
        return chatBoxView
     }
  }
    
 override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
      return true
  }
```

So every time I go to this viewController, I see the chatBoxView at the bottom of my screen, which is wanted. However, the keyboard isn't visible yet (only the chatBoxView), but why does my KeyBoardWillShow notification keep getting called?

Also, when the keyboard is up, then disappears when I tap the outside, KeyboardWillDisappear function gets called, but KeyBoardWillShow function gets called right after.

Here are the function for the Keyboard notifications.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

```
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {
            print("Notification: Keyboard will show")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.setBottomInset(to: keyboardHeight - self.chatBoxView.frame.height)
                self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
            }

        }
    }
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        print("Notification: Keyboard will hide")
        tableView.setBottomInset(to: 0.0)
    }
```

So basically, I get the log "Notification: Keyboard will show", when the keyboard isn't showing and only the accessory view. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using Simulator or real device?

Comment: @erictruong simulator

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are throwing away important information in the `UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. It is not enough just to look at the keyboard's height. You need to look at *where* the keyboard will be — look at its *entire* frame information. If the top of the keyboard is not going to be above the bottom of the screen, clearly you should not be doing anything. Similarly, if the keyboard frame is not going to be changing from where it was, you should not be doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

In simulator, make sure you show software keyboard.
Click here or `⌘  + K`

[image]